# is this a characterization of rational plane curves?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-curves

In Hartshorne's "Algebraic Geometry" there is this nice exercise I.7.5:

> If $Y$ is an irreducible plane curve of degree $d>1$ having a point of
>   multiplicity $d-1$ then $Y$ is a rational curve.

I wonder if the converse is true i.e. if I have a parameterizable/rational curve of degree $d$ can it happen that at all points of the curve the multiplicity is not $d-1$?

Comment: There are rational curves of degree $d$ in the plane with all its singular points ordinary nodes (so multiplicity 2).

Comment: Ah you are right. The lemniscate. Thanks.